# How to define table prefix in variable

Tags: php, sql, database, prefix

I want to define prefix in variable

```
global $wpdb;
    $prefix = 'qa_';
    $titles = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT title
        FROM "$prefixpages"
        }
    ");
```

Can anyone guide why its not working and hot to make it works.

Comment: are you looking for string concatenation in PHP? then you might want... to think about POINT. ( FROM ".$prefixpages."_TABLENAME )

Comment: Place your comment as an answer so I can select

Comment: However I voted your comment and was waiting for you to make it as a answer but you didn't so I am selecting other answer which is almost similar as yours but also have some more way to do. I really appreciate and thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to query from table qa_tages:

```
global $wpdb;
$prefix = 'qa_';
$titles = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT title
    FROM ${prefix}pages
    }
");
```

OR same line:

```
    ..."
    FROM ".$prefix."pages
    "...
```

if you need contents of $qa_pages variable:

```
global $wpdb;
$prefix = 'qa_';
$titles = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT title
    FROM ".${$prefix.'pages'}."
    }
");
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot but it is not echoing any output.. any clue? however I got code working with Najzero comment but I also would like to know if there is other way like yours

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 errors on this code :

1. This is a common mistake of (") 
   Please use (\") as the following example

   ```
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = 'qa_';
    $titles = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT title FROM \"$prefixpages\" } ");
   ```
2. You need to set space between variable declaration and table name
   Wrong : `$prefixpage`, right : `$prefix page`
3. The `}` at the end of the code is not needed. Why you put it?